# Cannot update firebase version

Tags: android, node.js, firebase

```
C:\Users\Kashish>npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: timed-out@^4.0.1 (node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\got\node_modules\timed-out):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: No valid versions available for timed-out
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-pre-gyp@^0.6.39 (node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 'C:\Users\Kashish\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\npm-shrinkwrap.json'

npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for timed-out

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kashish\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-06T19_37_44_647Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like npm is having issues right now https://status.npmjs.org/

This should work once npm is back to fully operational.