# Cannot install firebase-tools

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, npm, npm-install

I'm following this post to be able to schedule recurring notifications to my Android app via Firebase: [enter link description here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron)
The problem is that, at the end, when I have to deploy my functions at: `firebase functions:log --project <FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID>` My windows terminal says it doesn't recognize firebase command. So I tried to install firebase cli to have access to its commands. So, following [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/?hl=es-419) I installed Node.js but when I run `npm install -g firebase-tools` The following error shows up:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: pinkie-promise@^2.0.0 (node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\globby\node_modules\pinkie-promise):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: No valid versions available for pinkie-promise
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: timed-out@^3.0.0 (node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\got\node_modules\timed-out):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: No valid versions available for timed-out

npm ERR! code ENOVERSIONS
npm ERR! No valid versions available for pinkie-promise

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-06T20_45_10_832Z-debug.log
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131305/4815718

Comment: NPM is having problems.  Try again later.  https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/41zfb8qpvrdj